# How to move existing Apache configuration to another machine?

Tags: apache

I have an Apache (httpd) up and running on one machine. Now I want to move configuration details to another machine. The other machine should have the appropriate changes like creating Apache home directories, shares created, etc.

I want to automate the above process. How do I do that?

Comment: What distro? Can you provide more info?

Comment: both machines has same OS. RHEL 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any utility or script that will do that for you.  There are probably too many variables depending on your configuration.

Why do you want to automate the process?  If it's because you expect to do it more than once, here's what I recommend you do:

1. Copy all the files to the new machine with `scp`.  This should cover 95% of your configuration.
2. Perform any other configuration necessary, but do it all with the command line.
3. Copy your history into a script and keep it handy for next time.  It will probably require some tweaking to get it to run on its own.

Comment: @jeremy.. actually copying data is fine with me.. but the main automation i need is moving the configuration details..

Comment: I have a doubt in your reply .."Perform any other configuration necessary, but do it all with the command line." .. how to do that in command line? I thought of editing configuration in the new server...can you brief on that?

Comment: Most of your configuration is in the httpd.conf file.  It would be picked up in the file copy.  If you had some file or directory links or something else like that, you'd need to add the commands for making those changes.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy your httpd.conf and any other httpd access files, your content, move them to your new server in the corect places. make necessary configs like ip and ports and ...
then restart apache.(note:your apache servers should have same version.)

Answer (score 0):

I would agree to Jeremy.
I assume you are using UNIX.
You would need to FTP whole apache folder from source server to destination server.
something like ftp> mget *

And then you can start apache server on destination by running httpd.